# CSS color transition in triangles with linear gradient

Tags: html, css, background-color, linear-gradients

I am working on a rectangular background which is divided into 2 triangles by a line from top left to bottom right, as shown in the pic.

What I want to achieve is color transition in each triangle:

1. In triangle ABD: pink becomes darker from left to right
2. In triangle ACD: blue becomes darker from left to right

Note: The width and height are not fixed to 600 and 250. I just use them for demo purpose.

HTML code:

```
<div class="background-wrapper">
  <p class="float-left">A</p>
  <p class="float-right">B</p>

  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <p class="float-left">C</p>
  <p class="float-right">D</p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.background-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px 50px 80px 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, pink 50%, blue 50%);
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

[Demo jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wl880504/k76at0cL/)

[image]

Comment: have you tried `background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, lightpink, pink 50%, blue 50%, lightblue);` ? https://jsfiddle.net/k76at0cL/1/

Comment: I tried, but the transition direction is not from left to right.

Comment: You can add colors and you can even layer multiple backgrounds on top of each other.. But what you want can't be achieved with gradients only I think.. You possibly need canvas and all that.

Comment: gradient is not required, i am open to any methods. I just dont know how to implement it...

Comment: i see, i believe vals has the right answer using multiple gradients (did not get it at first) , similar example https://jsfiddle.net/k76at0cL/6/  you need to tune the first gradient. indeed, blend-mode would do a better job, but not enough supported yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One posibility, that is cross-browser but that gives *washed* colors, is to overlay the triangles with a semitransparent gradient that is white on one side and black in the other.

This effect gets much better using blend modes, but the support is lower.

```css
.test {
    width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,.5), rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%,
    rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,.5)), 
    linear-gradient(to top right, blue 50%, fuchsia 50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more colors after you define the linear-gradient position, so you can do stuff like:

```
background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, deeppink 0%, pink 50%, blue 50%,midnightblue 100%);
```

Check your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/k76at0cL/5/)

Comment: the transition direction is from bot left to top right rather than left to right

Comment: 50% instead of 51% to avoid blurring

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code quite a bit from the original. I added two new elements to act as the background. May not be the solution you're looking for but off the top of my head this is what works.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k76at0cL/3/)

```css
.background-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px 50px 80px 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -65%;
  right: -30%;
  width: 125%;
  height: 125%;
  transform: rotate(26.5deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, pink, #f44274);
}
.triangle.bottom {
  top: initial;
  right: initial;
  left: -30%;
  bottom: -64.8%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, navy);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-wrapper">
  <div class="triangle top"></div>
  <div class="triangle bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. One problem here is once the width or height changes, the rotation degree remains the same but the backbround is not 2 triangles any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
.background-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #ffffff;
/* Old Browsers */background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 0%, #6176ff 49%, #ff80d9 50%, #ffffff 100%);
 /* FF3.6+ */background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(49%, #6176ff), color-stop(50%, #ff80d9), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
/* Chrome, Safari4+ */background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 0%, #6176ff 49%, #ff80d9 50%, #ffffff 100%);
 /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 0%, #6176ff 49%, #ff80d9 50%, #ffffff 100%);
 /* Opera 11.10+ */background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 0%, #6176ff 49%, #ff80d9 50%, #ffffff 100%);
 /* IE 10+ */background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 0%, #6176ff 49%, #ff80d9 50%, #ffffff 100%);
/* W3C */filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );
/* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

you can specify the angle in the gradient. Try the above code. it works with width and height.